# NUnit console with dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, nunit, nunit-console

I'm using NUnit for unit testing, and I want to send some parameters through the nuni3-console.
But when I insert the unit test project I have this error.

command inserted: nunit3-console pathToMyProject

Error: 'Not possible to associate a transparent proxy to the type...'
[image]

I dont know what it's wrong, and there is any other framework to send parameters on windows cmd?

Comment: You don't give details of what runtime you are targeting, what framework version you are using, etc. However, the error makes me suspect that you are trying to run .NET Core or .NET Standard tests through the console, which is not supported.

Comment: Yes,  I am trying run the tests through the console using nunit, is not posible? Because I need to send parameters, do you know how can  I do it?

Comment: What runtime ar you targeting?